# Where was Theodred killed?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-two-towers

In the Peter Jackson extended version of The Two Towers, Theodred was picked up by Eomer and brought back to Meduseld.

With his father's "sickness" did Theodred really leave to fight the orcs?

Due to a house fire, I no longer have my precious (precious?) copies of the trilogy, The Hobbit or the Silmarillion, so I cannot check the info myself.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 23):

### Where did Théodred die?

Théodred died at the First Battle of the Fords of Isen; from Appendix B:

> **February 25, 1419 S.R.**  The Company pass the Argonath and camp at Parth Galen. First Battle of the Fords of Isen; Théodred son of Théoden slain.
>
> <sup><sub>*Return of the King* Appendix B "The Tale of Years" *(ii) The Third Age*</sub></sup>

Presumably the place of his death was the ford of the river Isen; Appendix A confirms that he was out fighting the Orcs of Saruman:

> *Éomer Éadig.* When still young he became a Marshal of the Mark (3017) and was given his father's charge in the east marches. In the War of the Ring Théodred fell in battle with Saruman at the Crossings of Isen.
>
> <sup><sub>*Return of the King* Appendix A "Annals of the Kings and Rulers" The Kings of the Mark</sub></sup>

Per *Unfinished Tales*, the exact place of his death was a small river-island in the middle of the Isen (bold is my emphasis, italics is Tolkien's):

> As soon as the enemy had gained possession of the eastern end of the Fords there appeared a company of men or Orc-men (evidently dispatched for the purpose), ferocious, mail-clad, and armed with axes. They hastened to the [eyot](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eyot) and assailed it from both sides. At the same time Grimbold on the west bank was attacked by Saruman's forces on that side of the Isen. As he looked eastward, dismayed by the sounds of battle and the hideous Orc-cries of victory, he saw **the axe-men driving Théodred's men from the shores of the eyot towards the low [knoll](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/knoll) in its centre**, and he heard Théodred's great voice crying *To me, Eorlingas!* At once Grimbold, taking a few men that stood near him, ran back to the eyot. So fierce was his onset from the rear of the attackers that Grimbold, a man of great strength and stature, clove his way through, till with two others **he reached Théodred standing at bay on the knoll. Too late. As he came to his side Théodred fell**, hewn down by a great Orc-man. Grimbold slew him and stood over the body of Théodred, thinking him dead; and there he would himself soon have died, but for the coming of Elfhelm.
>
> <sup><sub>*Unfinished Tales* Part III "The Third Age" Chapter 5: "The Battles of the Fords of Isen"</sub></sup>

### Did Théodred really go out fighting Orcs when his father was so sick?

Yes, of course he did. Théodred was the Second Marshal of the Riddermark, with a third of the Muster of Rohan under his command, and the safety of the West-mark was his responsibility.

The full story of the Battle of the Fords of Isen is told in *Unfinished Tales*, but the gist is that Saruman tricked him. Théodred was lured out into battle by the promise of an easy, decisive victory against Saruman's invasion force:

> Saruman's attack was not unforeseen, but it came sooner than was expected. Théodred's scouts had warned him of a mustering of troops before the Gates of Isengard, mainly (as it seemed) on the west side of Isen. He therefore manned the approaches, east and west, to the Fords with the sturdy men on foot from the levies of Westfold. Leaving three companies of Riders, together with horse-herds and spare mounts, on the east bank, he himself passed over with the main strength of his cav­alry: eight companies and a company of archers, intending to overthrow Saruman's army before it was fully prepared.
>
> But Saruman had not revealed his intentions nor the full strength of his forces. They were already on the march when Théodred set out.
>
> <sup><sub>*Unfinished Tales* Part III "The Third Age" Chapter 5: "The Battles of the Fords of Isen"</sub></sup>

Regardless of Théoden's health, Théodred's military responsibilities wouldn't allow him to ignore the threat of Saruman.

Comment: FGitW! Nice one :-)